# Add node to XML with condition

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
    </person>
</root>
```

And I have the following CSV file:

```
id;phone
1;12345678
2;78903456
```

I work with PHP. I need to do with XML something like this:
Add a phone number element to the person where id is...
For example: Add a phone element with value 12345678 to the person element with id 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the content of the XML will vary, it will probably be easier to XPath to find the entry you want to update...

```
$telephoneList = [["id"=> 1, "phone" => "12345678"],
        ["id"=> 2, "phone" => "78903456"]];

$xml = simplexml_load_file("a.xml");
foreach ( $telephoneList as $telephone) {
    $person = $xml->xpath("//person[id={$telephone['id']}]");
    if ( count($person) == 1 )   {
        $person[0]->addChild("phone", $telephone['phone']);
    }
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

This tries to find the `<person>` element with an `<id>` with the value from the csv.  If this is found, it will add in the phone number using `addChild()`

It's just a case of reading in the CSV file and process it as above.

Answer (score 1):

With SimpleXML, you can use the addChild() method.

```
$file = 'xml/config.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$galleries = $xml->galleries;

$gallery = $galleries->addChild('gallery');
$gallery->addChild('name', 'a gallery');
$gallery->addChild('filepath', 'path/to/gallery');
$gallery->addChild('thumb', 'mythumb.jpg');

$xml->asXML($file);
```

Be aware that SimpleXML will not "format" the XML for you, however going from an unformatted SimpleXML representation to neatly indented XML is not a complicated step and is covered in lots of questions here.

Comment: And Where is the where condition? A need to add concrete data to concrete persons?

Comment: loop through galleries, if for example; galleries[1]['user_id'] == 1 then add phone_number 12345678

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the `$xml->children()` from the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and then check if for `(string)$a->id === "1"`. Then use [addChild](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) to add your `phone` element with value `12345678` to the person element.

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $a) {
    if ((string)$a->id === "1") {
        $a->addChild("phone", "12345678");
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qVla9)